# pytorch convolutional layer with weights being a learnable function of the input

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I would like to define a pytorch model where some of the layers are convolutional layers, whose weights are an explicit function of the input (with learnable parameters).

Example: let's say we have 1 channel and 1 minibatch of 1.
Then given a 1-dimensional input vector `x` of size n, I can pass it into a 1-dimensional convolutional layer `nn.Conv1d(1, 1, k, bias = False)` to obtain an output vector of size n-k+1. If I wrap my convolution layer into a model, the model has now k learnable parameters (the weights of the 1-dimensional convolutional layer).

Now let's say that my input is actually a pair of 1-dimensional vectors `(x, y)` where `y` has size m.
I would like y to "control" the weights of the convolutional layer applied to x, in the sense that the weights of the convolutional layer are the vector `A * y` where A is a k-by-m matrix of learnable parameters.

Problem: I am confused on how to define the `nn.Module` class to satisfy the above requirements.
Let's say I start with a very simple model which just applies a 1-dimensional convolutional layer:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Conv1dModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size):
        super(Conv1dModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 1, kernel_size = kernel_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.conv1d(x)
        return output
```

Then I would like to modify the weight of the convolutional layer, which I can access with `self.conv1d.weights`.
But here's my confusion: I think that I can (should?) only modify module parameters (those access via `self.xyz`) in the initialization method `__init__`, but on the other hand in order to set `weights = Linear(m,k)(y)` I need the input vector y, which is not available at initialization time.

How do I solve this conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

So you could have a process where you generate a set of weights, then use the `torch.nn.functional.conv1d` function to apply the convolution using those weights. But I see an issue with this approach.

For a standard `conv1d` operation, your input will be of shape `(batch_size, in_channels, i*W)` and your weight will be of shape `(out_channels, in_channels, k*W)`. The issue is your input has a batch dimension, but your weights don't.

Your desired approach, as you describe it, would want a different set of weights for each `(x,y)` vector pair in the batch.

Given that all convolutions are a strict subset of matrix-vector multiplication, you're probably better off just concatenating `[x,y]` and putting them through a linear layer.

Comment: "Given that all convolutions are a strict subset of matrix-vector multiplication, you're probably better off just concatenating [x,y] and putting them through a linear layer." Are you suggesting to essentially re-implement convolution from scratch using linear layers, so that it does what I want?

Comment: I mean literally just concat them and put them through a linear layer. There's no point doing a convolution unless your input has a "channels" dimension or similar, which to my understanding is the case here. You also want your update operation to be different for every item in the batch (ie conditioned on different y vectors), which a convolution won't give you.